# SharePoint :How to know if an email contains an attachment using web.GetFile(guidOfEmail)

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

Is there a way to find out that an email contains an attachment if we upload an email with an attachment to sharepoint?

using  web.GetFile(GuidOfTheEmail)...

or any other method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Outlook VBA objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa210897(office.11).aspx) to parse through the msg file and get that information, or there is a pure .NET solution from [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.network-for-.net/default.aspx) which also has the ability to parse msg files, although the Aspose library will cost money.  I have had some experience with the Aspose libraries and have found them very easy to use and very efficient, but if you're looking for a free solution, you're probably going to need to do some COM interop work.